# Entity Framework not saving new column

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I added a new column to an object, and used EF to update the model from the database.

Normally we do the following:

```
context.BulkInsert(records, GetBulkInsertOptions());
context.SaveChanges();
```

But this doesnt seem to work for the new column. If I do the following it works, but is obviously not ideal.

```
foreach (var r in records)
{
    context.MyDBObject.Add(r);
    context.Entry(r).State = EntityState.Modified;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Can anybody shed some light on this? Additionally, if I erase the row in the database before it does a save, it will insert everything, except for the new column I added.

edit: Using Entity Framework v6.2.0 and EntityFramework.BulkInsert v6.0.3.8

edit 2:  If I erase the row, and try to insert a new object using only the following

```
context.MyTable.Add(test);
context.SaveChanges()
```

This also inserts the object, but doesnt include my new column. This leads me to believe its more an error with EF and less with the BulkInsert as I alluded to previously.

Comment: Might be related to this bug: https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Extensions/issues/279

Comment: Please always tag the EF version you're using.

Comment: @GertArnold Done. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Nicolas, EntityFramework.BulkInsert and Z.EntityFramework.Extensions is not the same library. So I'm not sure you are flagging the issue #279 on EFE in your comment.

Comment: Is your entity model corresponding to database's table ?

Comment: @RamilAliyev Yes it was. See my answer below for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was caused by Triggers in the table in Mssql.

Doing `context.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;` Helped us determine that Entity Framework was sending the right query to SQL. Testing the query in SQL showed that the new column wasn't being saved.